# How to import jenkins credentials into a jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I was following the jenkinsfile [documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#handling-credentials) and I tried to use a secret text in my pipeline but I got the error 
"groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY for class: groovy.lang.Binding"

This is my jenkinsfile. I also tried wrapping the variable like echo "${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}" but neither works. I found an alternative solution is with a withCredentials line but I want to know why it doesn't work because I found clearer the jenkins file if I add that data as variables.

Implementing "withCredentils" it tells me: "groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: set for class: groovy.lang.Binding" and I found that it seems I need to downgrade my security...

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    environment {
        AWS_ACCESS_KEY     = credentials('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
        AWS_SECRET_KEY = credentials('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
    }

    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                echo 'Testing..'
                echo $AWS_SECRET_KEY
                echo $AWS_ACCESS_KEY

            }
        }
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                echo 'Deploying....'
                sh "npx serverless --no-aws-s3-accelerate --key $AWS_ACCESS_KEY --secret $AWS_SECRET_KEY"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: fix second implementation of credentials

Comment: `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` is to my understanding the ID of the credential object. You need to use `$AWS_ACCESS_KEY` and `$AWS_SECRET_KEY` in the shell command.

Answer (score 1):

1.did you add the credentials with ID AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY  to you jenkins?

2. echo ${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}  will not work, because only the credentials steps can return the content of credentials into your pipeline context.
3. withCredentils <-- typo

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use 'withCredentials' (
https://plugins.jenkins.io/credentials-binding)

after you have created a new credential (AWS type) (using 'the CloudBees Aws Credential Plugin' :
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/CloudBees+AWS+Credentials+Plugin)

Im not very familiar with declarative pipeline syntax, so it might not be the best way to do it.

Anyway, you need to add a script block :

```
stage('Deploy') {
    steps {
        script {
            withCredentials([[
                class: 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding',
                credentialsId: awsCredentialId,
                accessKeyVariable: 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY',
                secretKeyVariable: 'AWS_SECRET_KEY'
            ]]) {
                    println 'Deploying....'
                    sh " npx serverless --no-aws-s3-accelerate --key $AWS_ACCESS_KEY --secret $AWS_SECRET_KEY"
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do u define Secret text class

Answer (score 0):

You should use variable inside double quote:

```
echo "$AWS_SECRET_KEY"
echo "$AWS_ACCESS_KEY"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply call the credentials like this.

```
 withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: "${jenkinsCredentialsId}", usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD')]) {
                 // your command here
            }
```